# grep not returning path when finding only 1 occurence

Tags: linux, unix, grep, find

For some ddl files containing a specific pattern I need the full path and filename. I am using the command: find /opt/releases/packages/cr666/sas/dbms -name *.ddl | xargs egrep -i -w "RENAME|MODIFY|^DROP TABLE"

In case of more than 1 found files, it returns what I need:

```
/opt/releases/packages/cr666/sas/dbms/sti/FA_BASKET.ddl:RENAME COLUMN;
/opt/releases/packages/cr666/sas/dbms/sti/FA_DISCLOSURE.ddl:MODIFY QUANTITY NUMBER;
```

However, If only 1 file is found it returns only the found line:

```
find /opt/releases/packages/cr_c_cr6/sas/dbms -name \*.ddl | xargs egrep -i -w "RENAME|MODIFY|^DROP TABLE"
alter table FA_DISCLOSURE MODIFY (ULINSTRUMENTID VARCHAR2(30 CHAR));
```

I am aware that if I use the option "-l" I get the result I need, but without the found line. Is there a way to get the same output for the second command as in the first example?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The -H option did the trick. About the squeezing with exec, sorry but I don't like it. squeezing code is making it harder to read and to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `-H` option of grep;

```
find ... | xargs egrep -iHw "RENAME|MODIFY|^DROP TABLE"
                         ^
```

From `man grep`:

> **-H, --with-filename**
>
> Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when there is
>   more than one file to search.

---

Also, note that the `find .. | xargs egrep` can be squeezed by using `-exec` in find as follows:

```
find $path -name *.ddl -exec egrep -iHw "RENAME|MODIFY|^DROP TABLE" {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your grep doesn't accept the "-H" option, just search in "/dev/null" as well - it doesn't take long and it'll never find anything in there ;-)